# How to create 2 separate lists based on a condition in scala

Tags: scala

I have 2 lists as my source datasets.

example:

```
val newList = Seq('ab', 'cd', 'ef')
val existingList = Seq('ab', 'xy', 'ij')
```

What i need is that when i compare the newList with the existing i need to prepare 3 different lists:

1. Elements to be skipped => Which exists in both the list
2. Elements to be deleted => Which is exists only in the Existing list but NOT in newList
3. Elements to be Added => Which is exists only in the NEW list but NOT in existingList

So expected output should be like:

```
val skipped: Seq[String] = Seq('ab') 
val added: Seq[String] = Seq('cd', 'ef') 
val deleted: Seq[String] = Seq('xy', 'ij')
```

Comment: And how Sets would help

Comment: Yes. But i don't want to use the diff, intersect method i have my own comparator method. And the example i have mentioned above is just for making example easy. In actual scenario i have Seq of case class

Comment: Well i never said its your fault and i don't expect you to answer as well its ok.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val newList = Seq("ab", "cd", "ef")
val existingList = Seq("ab", "xy", "ij")

val skipped: Seq[String] = newList.intersect(existingList)
val added: Seq[String] = newList.filterNot(existingList.contains)
val deleted: Seq[String] =existingList.filterNot(newList.contains)
```